# Causal Inference of Between-Group Differences in Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, inference, causality

I'm relatively new to time series data/causal inference (am working my way through Mostly Harmless Econometrics as we speak). Though, I'm still not sure how to appropriately test between-group differences in time series.

Basically, I want to test if the "red group" is statistically different from the "blue group". Here is an image of the two groups over time with log first differences on the y axis and time on the x axis:

[image: log firt differences between groups]

My first thought was that we could possibly test differences in the mean value given the distribution of the values on the y-axis looks like this:

[image]

But I'm not sure that makes sense. Can anyone provide suggestions for testing differences in these group and then cite sources I can read up on?

Comment: If vote is a character/factor variable, you can simply run a regression of your `y` variable on the vote variable in R. The intercept will capture the mean outcome value of one of the vote levels (e.g. Red). The coefficient of the vote variable will capture the mean difference in outcome between Red and Blue. The p.value of this coefficient will tell whether Red and Blue are statistically different.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

Right, which would really just be a t-test of the two distributions. Also... this seems like a fairly "naive" approach but also what I came up with.

Comment: Indeed it is, with the possibility of expansion to a much more robust model. You asked for "between-group differences in time series", and that is the best that can be done without any more knowledge about the data, the research question, and the program that you want to evaluate.

Comment: Yea - you're right. Probably best for me to just leave this one as observational/exploratory.